# reading xml with python when the attributes are empty

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML file to read with Python:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization version="9" signature="serialization::archive">
    <obj> 
        <count>2</count> 
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item>3.1400001</item>
        <item>7.3600001</item> 
    </obj> 
  </boost_serialization>
```

The python script I use to read this XML file is as follows:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('items.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
print(len(itemlist))
print(itemlist[0].attributes['ATTRIBUTE_NAME'].value)
```

The problem with the script is ATTRIBUTE_NAME does not exist. If I print it with print `itemlist[0].attributes.keys()`, it is empty. So in this case how I can obtain the item values `3.1400001` and `7.3600001` ?

Comment: `print(itemlist[0].firstChild.data)` ?

Comment: Any specific reason you picked the `minidom`? As the documentation for that module states, unless you really *have* to use the DOM API you want to be using the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead.

Comment: `itemlist = tree.findall('.//item'); for item in itemlist: print(item.text)`.